# How to get tagName for VML object?

Tags: javascript, vml

VML objects in IE8 throws exception when I try to access tagName attribute. Is it possible to get it in some other way?

Sample code that raises exception:

```
function clickCallback(event) {
  var target = event.srcElement;
  target.tagName; // Here exception raised
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you used? Thx

Comment: Updated with sample code

Comment: If the undisclosed exception message claims that there isn't such attribute (I wonder why everything seems to consider error messages irrelevant) there's no reason to think otherwise. Most likely, `target` does not contain what you assume.

Comment: This is callback on attachEvent to document, and I click on some polygon. ```'tagName' in target == true```, but exception is raised when I access element. If it is not VML object, what is it?

Comment: I don't know: I don't have access to your full code or your browser's console (or your exception message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: instead of `tagName`, `nodeName` attribute should be used.